Modified Elasticity Calculation
I have 5 yrs worth of price and unit sold data for retail products. Generally these products have MRP and sold at some discount. I want to create elasticity curve for these products. However over a period of time, the MRP has changed and hence the selling price.
If I use data after most recent price change, 80% of records will get discarded for many of the products. Hence, I wanted to use a standard measure which can be to handle these price changes. I was wondering, if we can take a ratio selling price and MRP to get a decimal value as a proxy for prices. Below is a sample scenario:

Is this an acceptable approach?
